# change of an image px

Tags: php, gd

I would like to change the color of an image (turn red almost) but I only creates a row and a half.
why?

```
<?php    
$imgname = "test/test.png";
$im = imagecreatefrompng($imgname);

$w = imagesx($im); // image width
$h = imagesy($im); // image height

for($i=0;$i<$w;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$h;$j++){
        $color=imagecolorallocatealpha ($im, 255, 0, 0,255);
        imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $color);
    }
}

$imgname = "test/result.png";
imagepng($im, $imgname ); // save image as png
imagedestroy($im);

echo "<img src='test/result.png'>";
?>
```

if I move "imagecolorallocatealpha" before "for" it works ... but in future I will need to have each a different color px

Comment: I suspect you can only allocate a limited number of colors. Even when they are all identical. But I'm not sure on this.

Comment: Try echoing the values for $w and $h before the for loop. What values are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The `alpha` parameter (last one in function `imagecolorallocatealpha`) should be between 0 and 127. Your value, 255, is out of range. If you make it fit [the specifications](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php), your code works on my machine.